# Matlab Correlation Function

Tags: matlab, correlation

```
function letter=read_char(imgn, num_letters)

global templates

comp=[ ];

for n=1:num_letters

    sem=corr2(imgn, templates{1,n});

    comp=[comp sem];

end

vd=find(comp==max(comp));
```

Can someon please explain what the 'FOR' loop does and how 'vd' is calculated?
Also, what is the variable 'comp' and what will it looks like as the array also contains itself and another variable 'sem' which is calculated from the corr2 function.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [for loop](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/for.html) creates a loop variable `n` that starts at 1 for the first loop and is incremented by 1 for each successive loop until it reaches `num_letters`. This means the loop will execute `num_letters` times.

The variable `comp` is first initialized to the [empty matrix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-86359.html) `[]`. Within the loop, a 2-D correlation coefficient is computed between the matrix `imgn` and another matrix `templates{1,n}` (indexed from a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html)) using the function [CORR2](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/corr2.html). The correlation coefficient `sem` is appended to the array `comp` using [horizontal concatenation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/specialcharacters.html). This will ultimately result in `comp` being a 1-by-`num_letters` array of correlation coefficients.

The variable `vd` stores the array indices where values in `comp` are equal to the maximum value found in `comp`. This is done using the functions [MAX](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/max.html) and [FIND](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/find.html) and the [comparison operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f0-40063.html#f0-38145) `==`.

In the future, I would urge you to first use the [online documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/) to try and help you better understand how MATLAB works. It is *very* good documentation. I've learned most of what I know from it. ;)